# How can make the div in the photo fill all the white space on the left side? It only fills fully to the right

Tags: html, css

[image]

the div fills the entire width on the right side. But the on the left side there is about 25px of white space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You likely have a margin on your body, I would try adding margin: 0; to your body's css

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```